# Charging a laptop with usb c charger but it does not support it will damage the port?

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging, charger

So there is a reverse charging thing built into smartphones nowadays.I connected my phone to the usb port of my laptop and my laptop said charging is not supported from this port and I saw that reverse charging feature was turned on.I wonder if I damaged the port or the battery.It was not showing charging on the laptop when I connected my phone but the pop up came.

Answer (score 0):

Without quite knowing which was attempting to charge which, or on which the pop-up happened, here's how it goes…

You connect 2 devices.
One says, "Ooh, you can charge me - that would be nice, tyvm."
The other says, "Nope, not gonna happen, because 'reasons'".
Result - nothing happens.
You get pop-up telling you "request denied".

There is no potential for damage, the devices figured out for themselves that it wouldn't work, so didn't do it.

Comment: What if the second device is not a USB C device? e.g. a "dumb" USB charger with a USB A -> USB C cable? That would certainly provide its 5V to the USB C port. Does USB C have protection against that?

Comment: Basically, if you can plug one USB into another, there has to be protection in place, otherwise there would be a lot of dozy people setting their houses on fire, every day.